# Select IF EXISTS THEN ELSE on Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried to solve this issue a lot, checked a lot of sites, tried more examples, but did not get what I want yet.
My sql logic on my php Page like at below:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM suborders WHERE subId = 1))
THEN SELECT * FROM suborders WHERE subId = 1     //if exists just do this sql again
ELSE SELECT id FROM orders WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1;
```

Mysql Gives an error on syntax at the first query. So, I also tried to use another way at below:

```
delimiter //
create procedure test()
begin
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM suborders WHERE subId = 1) THEN
SELECT * FROM suborders WHERE subId = 1;
ELSE
SELECT id FROM orders WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1;
END IF;
end //
delimiter ;

call test();
```

Using 2nd query mysql returns empty result, without error. Actually, there should be something to fetch...

Comment: In this case, I think doing the logic in PHP makes more sense.

Comment: Is `subId` a foreign key to `orders.id`, or the other way around? If they are related, you can do  a left join, and handle the cases based on the rowset returned

Comment: This query seems really fishy in data terms.

Comment: @RiKo My point was to `SELECT orders LEFT JOIN suborders` such that the result would be NULL for the suborders columns, while orders.id would always be present. In your application code, you can detect that and act accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, yes, subId is a foreign key. left join returns empty result when first query NOT EXISTS. Maybe, I missed something... Can you write it below as answer?

Comment: @RiKo I went ahead and typed up what I was referring to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM suborders WHERE subId = 1 )
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM suborders WHERE subId = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT id FROM orders WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1
END
```

**Full stored Procedure:**

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE sp_select_suborders(IN `p_subId`)
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM suborders WHERE subId = p_subId )
    BEGIN
       SELECT * FROM suborders WHERE subId = p_subId
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT id FROM orders WHERE id = p_subId LIMIT 1
    END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

**Usage:**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('CALL sp_select_suborders(?)');
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM suborders WHERE subId = 1 ) BEGIN SELECT * FROM su' at line 1

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes I Know this, I wrote it like this because he mention he wants to use an SP

Comment: You are right @Mike i wouldnt use a wildcard either, sp returning different resultset schema is certainly not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simple handle the case of no results in php?

```
$yourDBUsage->query("SELECT * FROM suborders WHERE subId = 1"); 

if ($yourDBUsage->count == 0){
   $yourDBUsage->query("SELECT id FROM orders WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1;");
}
```

Comment: So in this case here are 2 queries =)

Comment: @RiKo, Right. You do the first one, and if it returns zero rows, you do the second one. Its cleaner than your attempts which is actually 3 queries.  You were doing the first one TWICE, if it did return something, and were still doing the first once and second once if nothing was returned by the first.

Comment: @RiKo so what? Don't try to wrap everything into single queries, unless your database can only handle 3 queries per second :) (It wouln't mind some thousands)

Comment: Actually my queries are not simple ;) Here I wrote simple queries like an example :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `suborders.subId` is a foreign key referencing `orders.id`, you can approach your query logic with a single `LEFT JOIN` query.  I would prefer this solution because it means you do not have to maintain a stored procedure separately. All the query logic is bundled with your application code.

By doing a `LEFT JOIN` from `orders` against `suborders`, columns from `suborders` may return `NULL`.  In your application code, you may then test if they are null, and if they are, use the `id` from `orders` instead.  This method essentially transfers the flow logic to your PHP code, while stuffing all the database actions into one query, which will either return one row, or many rows (or none, if the requested id doesn't exist in `orders`)

```
SELECT
  orders.id AS orders_id,
  suborders.*
FROM
  orders
  LEFT JOIN suborders ON orders.id = suborders.subId
WHERE orders.id = ?
```

In the PHP logic, execute that query with an appropriate value in place of `?`. When fetching, you will be able to discern immediately if `suborders` has no return, as all the `suborders` columns will be `NULL`.

```
// Assume fetched into $orders
foreach ($orders as $order) {
  if ($order['subId'] === null) {
    // Use orders.id...
    // If it is a unique id, this will be the only row
    // and the loop will terminate here
    echo $order['orders_id'];
  }
  else {
    // subId has a value, so you can use the other suborders cols
    echo $order['subId'];
    echo $order['other_suborder_column'];
  }
```

This way, if `suborders` does match and populate columns, you would be able to loop over the entire returned rowset, equivalent to `SELECT * FROM suborders`.  Otherwise, you can break the loop right away (or if `orders.id` is unique as I suspect it is, it will only ever return one row anyway with an `orders_id` and null `suborders`).

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it is impossible to accept 2 answers together. I mean your and meda's answers ;)